# How to integrate facebook user account?

Tags: django, facebook

I'm building a new website[in django], in which i want to integrate particular users facebook account in the site [while he/she is registering]. Can you suggest me how to integrate it in my site.

Comment: Check out [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for facebook only, check out [django-facebook](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook). It has good FB integration.